# How can I make EditText go to URL or search Google?

Tags: android, url, android-edittext

I have created a web browser that is functional, but I'm trying to implement code that will make the EditText address bar search Google if the user doesn't enter a suffix like .com/.org etc. I need it to work like any other modern browser that will allow the user to search right from the address bar. I have tried several different if/else statements that should achieve the desired result, but each throws an error of some sort. Any ideas out there?

This is code that works but doesn't achieve the desired result, it only calls the URL:

```
     WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
String current_page_url = "http://www.google.com";
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
EditText editText;
Button btnLaunchWebsite2;
String edittextvalue;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        current_page_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    }

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    initWebView();
    webView.loadUrl(current_page_url);
    btnLaunchWebsite2 = findViewById(R.id.btnLaunchWebsite2);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_content);

    btnLaunchWebsite2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String editextvalue = editText.getText().toString();

            if (!editextvalue.startsWith("http://"))
                editextvalue = "http://" + editextvalue;



            String url = editextvalue;
            webView.loadUrl(url);


            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);


        }
    });
}


private void initWebView() {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            current_page_url = url;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
```

In the problem area,this is code that I tried but throws errors every way I try it:

```
     btnLaunchWebsite2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override      
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    String url = editText.getText().toString();
    if (url != " ") {
    }
    if (url.contains(".") && url.contains(" ") || url.length() < 4) {
        url = "https://www.google.com.np/search?q="
                + editText.getText().toString();
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
    if (url.contains(".com") || url.contains(".")) {
        if (url.contains("http://") || url.contains("https://")) {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        } else if (editText.getText().toString().contentEquals("")) {
        } else {
            url = "http://" + editText.getText().toString();
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    } else {
        if (editText.getText().toString().contentEquals("")) {
        } else {
            url = "https://www.google.com.np/search?q="
                    + editText.getText().toString();
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not able to meanig of   if (url.contains(".") && url.contains(" ") || url.length() < 4) { is getting issue in to it?

Comment: @Android User: I don't think I understand what you're saying. Can you explain further?

Comment: i mean please check  if (url.contains(".") && url.contains(" ") || url.length() < 4) { codition and put debug over here in which case this execute